# XML implementation in ILOG

Tags: ilog

I want to pass xml as an input to the rule project. I want to call the ILOG rules using webservices. xml type object is not available in ILOG parameter types. Can any one suggest how I can pass xml as an input to ILOG rules and manipulate the xml data inside the rules with an example. An I would like to call this rule using a webservice.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

how would u like to invoke your code? via web service or an J2SE session?

if u r trying to hit your RES, then u must send SOAP request using the WSDL file, which u can retreive from the RES admin console. u can use software like SOAPUI to send soap request using the wsdl file.

if u want to run your rules in a Java session without ANY involvment of the RES u have to create a J2SE stateless/statful session and create a IrlXMLObject